# Django-Unicorn: django_unicorn.errors.ComponentModuleLoadError: The component module 'views_unicorn' could not be loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a Django Application where I need a partial refresh and I wanted to implement django-unicorn. It works locally but on the server, I am getting this error.

The server runs gunicorn.
The setup I tried to follow and based my items on it in the documentation here: https://www.django-unicorn.com/docs/direct-view/#template-requirements

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 84, in sentry_wrapped_callback
    return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_unicorn/decorators.py", line 16, in timed
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_unicorn/views/__init__.py", line 49, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 43, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_unicorn/views/__init__.py", line 555, in message
    json_result = _handle_component_request(request, component_request)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_unicorn/views/__init__.py", line 408, in _handle_component_request
    return _process_component_request(request, component_request)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_unicorn/views/__init__.py", line 86, in _process_component_request
    component = UnicornView.create(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_unicorn/decorators.py", line 16, in timed
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_unicorn/components/unicorn_view.py", line 927, in create
    raise ComponentModuleLoadError(message, locations=locations)
django_unicorn.errors.ComponentModuleLoadError: The component module 'views_unicorn' could not be loaded.
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form unicorn:submit.prevent="scan_ean">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input
                                                    id="scanned-ean"
                                                    class="textinput form-control"
                                                    name="scanned-ean" placeholder="EAN Number"
                                                    autofocus
                                                    unicorn:model.defer="ean_number"
                                                    unicorn:keyup.escape="ean_number=''"
                                            />
                                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0;"></span>
                                            <input id="scanned-ean-quantity-overide"
                                                   class="textinput form-control"
                                                   name="scanned-ean-quantity-overide"
                                                   placeholder="QTY Override"
                                                   unicorn:model.defer="scan_quantity_overide"
                                                   unicorn:keyup.escape="scan_quantity_overide=''"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button unicorn:click="scan_ean">Scan</button>
                                </form>
```

Then my view:

```
class OrderPickListView(UnicornView):
    order: Order
    template_name = 'pim/order_list_picking.html'
    ean_number: str
    scan_quantity_overide: str
    scan_error: str
    order_id: int

    def mount(self):
        self.ean_number = ''
        self.scan_quantity_overide = ''
        self.scan_error = ''
        self.order_id = self.kwargs['order_id']
        self.order = Order.objects.get(id=self.order_id)

    def scan_ean(self):
        self.scan_error='test'
```

I think what bothers me the most is that localhost on a docker with mostly the same setup it works ok.